# Assigning different layouts to activity on listView item click

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to open an activity with different layouts when `listView` item changes.when I click on item first only a blank screen appears,then after a single second it opens the layout given in the `else` condition.help me solve the problem

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.male);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_stars_male);
    Resources res = getResources();
    star_names = res.getStringArray(R.array.starnames);
    star_dates = res.getStringArray(R.array.stardates);
    MaleLikeDislikeAdapter adapter = new MaleLikeDislikeAdapter(this,star_names,star_images, star_dates );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position==0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.shahid.myapp.List_Activity");
                startActivity(intent);
                la.setContentView(R.layout.listviewlayout);
               // la is an object of List_Activity to which i want to set different layouts on item click
            }
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.shahid.myapp.List_Activity");
                startActivity(intent);
                la.setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I think the problem is because the setContentView and startActivity() are on the same block, try removing the setContentView and putting it inside the activity.

Comment: it is set in activity,when approaching to the activity on item click  i want to change the default layout to layout which i am passing in if/else condition.

Answer (score 1):

You should use fragment instead of doing this. Fragment is a same as activity but in actual it's a part of activity. you can use multiple fragments in single activity screen. For more information about fragments and for information how to use it check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) document.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion Jaydip but i have about to done having little problem...if it feels complicated to solve then probably i will take your suggestion in cosideration..